App must target Android 14 (API level 34) or later
I increased the target API level of the project from 33 to 34. The build process was successful. When I ran it with the emulator in Visual Studio Xcode, it did not throw any errors. However, when the application is loaded into the emulator and starts, it stops and closes the application. When I open the project in Android Studio and examine it in logcat, it throws the following error.
NOTİCE!!!!! When I create a device with Pixel 6 Pro Api 33 in Android Device Manager and run the project, the application opens. However, the same project does not open with Pixel 6 Pro API 34 even though I did not make any changes. I don't know if there is something I need to add to the MainApplication.java or AndroidManifest file.
When my app is installed on the Emulator and I click to open it, this error message is thrown.

buildscript { ext { buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0" minSdkVersion = 21 compileSdkVersion = 34 targetSdkVersion = 34 ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529" // Any of the following will work // googlePlayServicesVersion = "17.0.0" playServicesVersion = "18.0.0" // playServicesLocationVersion = "17.0.0" } }
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
Also i changed -> android/app/build.gradle--> implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" to dependencies {....implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.67.2"}
AndroidManifest.xml permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

Android Studio: Flamingo 2022.2.1 Patch 1
LOGCAT LOG ERROR:
07-11 09:48:21.855  6868  6868 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.testreactnative, PID: 6868
07-11 09:48:21.855  6868  6868 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.testreactnative.MainApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but BridgeDevSupportManager class was not found or could not be created
07-11 09:48:21.855  6868  6868 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.testreactnative.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:55)
07-11 09:48:21.855  6868  6868 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.testreactnative: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
07-11 09:48:21.874   561  2080 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.testreactnative/.MainActivity

Please paste all information on the question. Do not answer your question with more information. As aswers are upvoted context will be lost.

try to set compileSdkVersion = 33 then run i hope it works

Same warning from Play Store - App must target Android 14 (API level 34) or higher
Using react native version - 0.70.8
How to fix it?

When I create a device with Pixel 6 Pro Api 33 in Android Device Manager and run the project, the application opens. However, the same project does not open with Pixel 6 Pro API 34 even though I did not make any changes. I don't know if there is something I need to add to the MainApplication.java or AndroidManifest file. I followed the steps in the https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/setup-sdk document but I couldn't find anything.

Please refer this I resolved the same error by making the mentioned changes.

Recently I also needed to update my app's API level. In fact, making the compileSdkVersion lower than the targetSdkVersion seems to work, but while researching I noticed that this is not a recommended practice. I identified this here and here, for example. I know it's a difficult process, but I think it's worth trying to update the compileSdkVersion as well, and keep compileSdkVersion lower than targetSdkVersion only as a last resource.
In my case, I needed to make several updates to fix the side effects of the application's dependencies, updates that I will list below. Of course, other projects will probably need different configurations, but I hope this works for applications that have similar dependencies as mine.

API level
Changes in android/build.gradle:
Before
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 33
buildToolsVersion = "33.0.2"

After
compileSdkVersion = 34
targetSdkVersion = 34
buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"

I have changed buildToolsVersion because of this page that says that "You should always keep your Build Tools component updated".
While updating the API version I started getting the following error:
Android Gradle build error "AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon."

This answer gave me an insight that the issue was related to gradle, so I changed Gradle and Gradle Plugin versions:

Gradle
Changes in android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties
Before:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip

After:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip


Changes in android/build.gradle
Before:
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2')
classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.0'

After:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
classpath "com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1"
    

Note: I also needed to upgrade Firebase's plugin version because of this error:
Unable to load class AndroidComponentsExtension

I solved it thanks to this answer.
Important: keep in mind that the Gradle version is not the same as the Gradle Plugin version. This information is relevant so that you know how to choose the correct and compatible versions of Gradle and Gradle Plugin, instead of blindly trying to make it work.

Other tweaks
These updates ended up causing some problems with the libs in my package.json. This part is very specific and you may not have any errors, or you may have different errors, but in case it is useful to someone I will describe the fixes I made:
Changes in package.json
Before:
"react-native": "0.65.3",
"react-native-screens": "3.10.2",
"react-native-webview": "11.13.1"

After:
"react-native": "0.66.5",
"react-native-screens": "3.22.1",
"react-native-webview": "11.22.7"

I also needed to add resolutions, as below:
"resolutions": {
  "@react-native-community/cli": "^7.0.0",
  "@react-native-community/cli-config": "^7.0.0",
  "@react-native-community/cli-debugger-ui": "^7.0.0",
  "@react-native-community/cli-doctor": "^7.0.0",
  "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^7.0.0",
  "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^7.0.0",
  "@react-native-community/cli-server-api": "^7.0.0",
  "@react-native-community/cli-tools": "^7.0.0",
  "@react-native-community/cli-types": "^7.0.0"
}

Why those updates in package.json?
I needed to update the WebView because the app was not building correctly. I was able to fix it with the help of this page.
For React Native Screens, I came across the following error:
Type mismatch: inferred type is Canvas? but Canvas was expected

I fixed it by using this suggestion.
Now about React Native: due to the update of React Native Screens the app started to present a bug in the keyboard. I was able to fix it thanks to this answer.
Finally, for the resolutions, I added them because I started facing the error below, fixed thanks to this answer:
Could not find method exec() for arguments [ReactNativeModules$_getCommandOutput_closure16@4a1214df] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProviderFactory_Decorated

As I said before, the tweaks in package.json are very specific, so you may encounter other errors. In any case, I hope I have given you some insight into this headache that is Android API level updates.

EDIT:
Error: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified
Some devices started to show an error after the API update:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException
One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts 

Caused by:
com.github.yamill.orientation.OrientationModule.onHostResume

Apparently, when updating the API level this problem can happen with several React Native libs (it seems that it happened to @Alan too). In my case, the problem was in the react-native-orientation lib.
I fixed it thanks to this page, by creating a patch after changing two files:
node_modules/react-native-orientation/android/build.gradle
Original code from react-native-orientation:
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}

Final result:
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

def getExtOrDefault(name, defaultVal) {
    return rootProject.ext.has(name) ? rootProject.ext.get(name) : defaultVal
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion getExtOrDefault('compileSdkVersion', 23)
    buildToolsVersion getExtOrDefault('buildToolsVersion', "23.0.1")

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion getExtOrDefault('minSdkVersion', 16)
        targetSdkVersion getExtOrDefault('targetSdkVersion', 22)
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // ndk {
        //     abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        // }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}

And then I fixed the second file:
node_modules_react-native-orientation/android/src/main/java/com/github/yamill/orientation/OrientationModule.java
You need to replace this line:
activity.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("onConfigurationChanged"));

with this one (don't forget to add the import):
import android.os.Build;

// ...

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && activity.getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= 34) {
    activity.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("onConfigurationChanged"), Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
} else {
    activity.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("onConfigurationChanged"));
}

Finally, execute the command:
yarn patch-package react-native-orientation

and you're done.

You are a god, thank you.

Hello , very detailed answer, what is your JDK version ? or it doesn't matter? I am doing the same thing , my JDK is 11 , Gradle is 6.9.4 and Gradle Plaugin is 4.2.2
googlePlayServicesLocationVersion = "20.0.0"         buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"         minSdkVersion = 26         compileSdkVersion = 34         targetSdkVersion = 34         supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"         appCompatVersion = "1.3.1"         kotlinVersion = "1.6.10"
updating buildToolsVersion to 34.0.0
Installed Build Tools revision 34.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

@tony in my case I am using JDK 11 (version 11.0.12).

I received this error when trying to update my React Native app, from android target API level 33 to 34. And I solved it like this:
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 34

I changed only the targetSdkVersion.
I left the compleSdkVersion at 33, and gradleWrapper and the rest of configurations as they were.
Took this solution from here

And also updated my MainApplication and app/build.gradle as christophby suggested

MainApplication.java

// Add imports
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

// ...

// Put this above  "public void onCreate()":
  @Override
  public Intent registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= 34) {
      return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
    } else {
      return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
  }
// ....


and

app/build.gradle

dependencies {
     //  ...
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'
    // ...
}


Could you please specify your gradle version?

it works in debug mode but in release mode like playstore inner test. app crash still happen... how can i fix it?

getting this after adding the above code => cannot find symbol
return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);

Did you change your Node version or anything like it ?

At first, it didn't work for me. But after changint the way to add the dependency, it worked.
I've changed it
from: implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'
to: implementation("org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2")

in my case,
react: 16.13.1,
react-native: 0.67.4
node: 16.18.0

modified android\build.gradle
    buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0" // previous "30.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 24 // prevous 23
    compileSdkVersion = 33 // previous 30
    targetSdkVersion = 34 // previous 30

and generated the android build successfully.

But this solution only saves today. Some incompatibilities will occur. My recommendation is "targetsdk" ,"buildToolsVersion" and "compilesdk" should be 34. When I tried with 33, the app would sometimes close itself in the emulator. There was an incompatibility and I couldn't risk it. So I made them all 34. You can follow the path of the friend whose solution was 34 in the answers.

okay Kıvanç ARSLAN, i'll make a note of it.

This works, at least for now.

this work for me just increase the version of targetSdkVersion from 33 to 34 now uploaded to playstore
